# Using a SKAction to periodically change the background color of a SKScene

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm attempting to periodically change the background color of my SKScene node every 10 seconds.  I'm using a SKAction to fade the SKScene background color to a new, randomly generated color, with the fade action lasting for 4 seconds.  Right now, my attempted implementation uses a 'helper' SKSpriteNode to:

1. obtain a new background to use
2. set its color
3. apply an alpha fade action to it
4. and set it as the first node in my SKScene's node tree

In addition, I have some time keeping code to make sure that the background color on my SKScene is only changed once every 10 seconds. This means that if I assume SpriteKit aiming for 60FPS, the background color should be changed once every 600 seconds.  Since each background color fade action should last 4 seconds, each fade should take 240 seconds (again, assuming 60FPS to keep it simple).  Basically, there would be a period of 360 seconds where nothing is happening with the background color.

Anyway, I can't seem to get my code to currently work, as the color doesn't change at all.  The default background color I set for my SKScene (within my init method) is RGB white.  This is the only color that displays each frame.  In addition, 'timeSinceUpdateCalled' and 'timeSinceTheLastBackgroundColorChange' are both initially set to 0.0
Everything is driven from the SKScene's -update:(CFTimeInterval) method.  Code below:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {/* Called before each frame is rendered.  Basically, any actions taken on the title scene will go in here*/

    CFTimeInterval timeSinceUpdate = currentTime - self.timeSinceUpdateCalled;

    self.timeSinceUpdateCalled = currentTime;

    [self changeBackgroundTitleColorEverySoOften:timeSinceUpdate];
}


-(void)changeBackgroundTitleColorEverySoOften:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceUpdate{

    self.timeSinceTheLastBackGroundColorChange += timeSinceUpdate;

    if(self.timeSinceTheLastBackGroundColorChange > 10.0){

        self.timeSinceTheLastBackGroundColorChange = 0;

        [self renderNewTitleBackGroundColor];
    }
}

-(void)renderNewTitleBackGroundColor{

    _batball_titlehelpersprite = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:self.colorGenerator size:self.view.bounds.size];

    _batball_titlehelpersprite.alpha = 0.0;


    SKAction* titleactioncolorfade = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:4];

    titleactioncolorfade.speed = 1.0;

    [_batball_titlehelpersprite runAction:titleactioncolorfade];


    [self insertChild:_batball_titlehelpersprite atIndex:1];
}

-(UIColor* )colorGenerator{//This method generates a random UIColor

    UIColor* generatedColor = nil;//The generated random color

    generatedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:[BatBallUtils randomFloat2:255] green:[BatBallUtils randomFloat2:255] blue:[BatBallUtils randomFloat2:255] alpha:0.0];//Generate a random color

    return generatedColor;
}
```

I stepped through this code, and it seems that everything should work.  My UIColor generator code works as expected as well.  This is the code I use to generate a random float number between 2 and 255 for RGB:

```
+(float)randomFloat2:(int)maxNum{//Generate a random float number between two floating point min and max numbers


    float num = (arc4random() % maxNum) / (float)maxNum;

    return(num);

}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you post the entire randomFloat2 method. I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Hi.  I actually did post the entire method for randomFloat2.  I will take a look back at that method, but for now, I tested my code out again by returning a static UIColor (black) from my colorGenerator method to see if I would get a color fade change to black.  This still didn't happen

Comment: Ah, you need to indent the first line of that method by 4 spaces in your question. The randomFloat2 method returns a value between 0 and 254.0/255.0 not 2 and 255. Ironically, that's closer to what UIColor uses for its RGB values (see the answer by LearnCocos2D).

Answer (score 0):

UIColor values are in the range 0.0 to 1.0, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:

Also be sure to use 1.0 for alpha otherwise the color might not render at all because it's fully transparent.

Comment: I posted another comment about testing out fading and changing just to the color black ([UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.0]) by inserting that call in my return from my colorGenerator method.  Shouldn't alpha be 0 since I'm using an action (fadeInwithDuration) to transform alpha to 1?

Comment: Nevermind.....You were right, alpha should be set to 1.  I now get the random color changes as expected, but it doesn't seem that my SKAction is running.  The changes in color are abrupt and instant, not gradual and smooth over my specified 4 seconds for my SKAction.....I'm not entirely sure what the issue is yet, but this is progress

Comment: you seem to add a new sprite for every color change, did you think of removing the previous sprite as well? otherwise you'll have many sprites overlapping which will affect fading and color

Comment: LearnCocos2D, you are exactly correct.  I was going to take care of that problem next, but wanted to get the background color transitioning working first before I tackled that issue.